# How to add Bootstrap Tour JavaScript to WordPress Admin Panel Dashboard Widget

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

I am developing a theme and want to know how to add Bootstrap Tour Script to a Custom Dashboard Widget.

Basically I want to include the Bootstrap Tour Script to the Admin Panel so I can write a Custom Dashboard Widget and then link the Tour Script to that widget.

Answer (score 1):

***Step-1* → Download:**

Download the necessary CSS / JS files for Bootstrap Tour in your theme's directory.

***Step-2* → Tour setup script:**

Follow the instructions from [bootstraptour](https://bootstraptour.com/) for **the Tour setup script.** For example, the following script will load the Tour on the main WordPress Admin Panel Dashboard (on page load) and show the tour for default WP `Activity` & `At a Glance` Widgets:

> **Note:** Check the comments inside the CODE for more instructions:

```
// bootstrap-tour.js file
(function($) {

    var tour = new Tour({
        backdrop: true,
        steps: [
        {   
            element: "#dashboard_right_now",
            title: "Summary Widget.",
            content: "This widget shows the summary of your WP installation."
        },  
        {   
            element: "#dashboard_activity",
            title: "Activity Widget.",
            content: "This is WP Dashboard Activity Widget."
        }]  
    }); 

    tour.init();

    // This will load on each page load or refresh.
    // You may want to change this behaviour according to your need.
    // e.g. show the tour on a click even of a custom notice or button
    // within admin panel dashboard.
    $( window ).load( function() {
        tour.start( true );
    }); 
})( jQuery );
```

***Step-3* → Load the Script in Admin Panel:**

Use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) hook to add the Bootstrap Tour CSS and JS files in the Admin Panel Dashboard like the following CODE in your Theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpse308865_bootstrap_tour_enqueue_scripts( $admin_page ) { 
    if ( 'index.php' != $admin_page ) { 
        // so basically we're allowing the tour only on the main dashboard
        // change this if you want it elsewhere as well.
        return;
    }   
    // this is bootstrap tour css and js file inside theme's directory
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap_tour_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css', false, '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_tour_css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_tour_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );

    // this is the custom bootstrap tour loading script inside theme's directory
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_tour', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-tour.js', array( 'bootstrap_tour_js' ), '1.0' );
}   
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse308865_bootstrap_tour_enqueue_scripts' );
```

---

> **Note:** This is just a demonstration of how to add the CSS & JavaScript CODE of Bootstrap Tour in the WordPress Admin Panel Dashboard from your theme. Obviously you'll have to adjust the above CODE to fit your need accordingly.